# Is it possible to derive Private key from RSA public key with sufficiently powerful Quantum computer?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

Is it possible to derive private key directly from public key alone using a powerful Quantum computer.

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/88158/is-rsa-oaep-secure-against-shors-factoring-algorithm

Comment: Using Shor's algorithm to solve the factorization problem 
implies the derivation of the private key from RSA public key